# regexp to extract custom tag from text

Tags: php, regex

Language: PHP

I have string of text with custom tag, like this:

```
text text <mention userid="1" username="Jack Smith"> text text
```

I am not too good with regular expressions so I could not really figure out how to:

1) extract all this mentions with ID and username

2) replace mentions with NAME

So, basically I need something like this:

```
function get_all_mentions($text)
{
}
// returns an array:
1 => Jack Smith
... => ...
```

and

```
function replace_all_mentions($text)
{
}
// returns a string
text text <a href="user/1">Jack Smith</a> text text
```

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Never use regex to parse HTML tags. Use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks, will use it. Changed format to text text text <mention userid="1">Jack Smith</mention> text text

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleHTMDom :

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

```
<?php

include 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';

 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load('text text <mention userid="1" username="Jack Smith" /> text text');

 $element = $html->find("mention");


/**
* For get username attr
*/
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($element[0]->attr['username']);
 echo '</pre>';


#for change username
 $element[0]->username = 'Hi';

# and echo Or $html->save('a.html')
 echo $html;
```

Comment: I assume `smiplehtmldom` should be `simplehtmldom`.

Comment: oh OK.It's just spelling mistake;)

Comment: You should change your answer. People might copy-paste it without reading it.

Comment: Don't worry. I changed it